# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column

Tags: php

I am getting this error, i make sure all names are correct and idk what's wrong, seems like nothing is added in rsn column. Been searching around and i know issue but i don't know what is causing my issue and if you can comment my code if it's injectable, first time using PDO.

html

```
<form action="rsdenar.php" method="post">
    <div id="gold-calc">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="amount"><h3><i class="fa fa-database">&nbsp;Kolicina</i></h3></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="gpamount">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" style="margin-top:30px; width: 70%;" id="goldtype">
                <option value="0.5">RS3</option>
                <option value="1.6">RS 07</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="price"><h3><i class="fa fa-database">&nbsp;Cena</i></h3></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price">
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 170px;">
            <label for="idrsn">RSN: </label> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idrsn" name="rsn" style="width: 40%">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="emailbuy">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailbuy" name="email-nakup" style="width: 40%;">
        </div>
       <div class="buy-order">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="#"><h5 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 20px">NAKUP</h5></a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

php

```
<?php

include 'php_includes/db_connect.php';

try {

    $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO purchase (rsn,email,amount,unique_id)
        VALUES (:rsn, :email, :amount, :unique_id)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':rsn', $_POST['rsn']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email-nakup']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':amount', $_POST['gpamount']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':unique_id', $_POST['unique_id']);
    $stmt->execute();

}catch (exception $e){
    echo $e;
}


?>
```

sql

[image]

Comment: what is your purchase table structure (including foreign keys and any other primary key)?

Comment: @PerdeepSingh updated

Comment: You have an undefined variable `$_POST['unique_id']`

Comment: @JayBlanchard i removed that to insert and still same thing 'rsn cannot be null'

Comment: *That's* the error? You never told us that before.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'rsn' cannot be null in

Comment: Should be easy to fix, no?

Comment: It sounds easy but give me hints

Comment: Put a `print_r($_POST);` as the first line of your PHP script. Fill out the form, hit submit and let us know what is printed out.

Comment: Array ( [gpamount] => 3 [rsn] => 333 [email-nakup] => a@gmail.com ) Connected successfully

Comment: That should work unless you have other issues in the code we're not aware of. You still need to define the unique_id.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i didn't auth frontend of my application and i always added null into my db fields. Now i know it's best to validate frontend and backend, could you give me backend validation example for my case aswell? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error states, `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'rsn' cannot be null in`, so you will need to always check if the value of `rsn` is empty before you try to insert the data on the table.

You can do this by this way on your PHP code:

```
<?php
// validation added here
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['rsn'])) {
    try {

        $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO purchase (rsn,email,amount,unique_id) VALUES (:rsn, :email, :amount, :unique_id)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':rsn', $_POST['rsn']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email-nakup']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':amount', $_POST['gpamount']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':unique_id', $_POST['unique_id']);
        $stmt->execute();

    }catch (exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }

}
```